# run a script when a new veth interface is added

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, docker, system-administration

Docker creates a `veth` interface connected to a bridge (`docker0`) for each of the containers it create.

http://docs.docker.io/use/networking/

I want to limit the bandwidth these new `veth` interfaces have. I found a way to do this with wondershaper. However I want to automate this.

Is there a way to have a hook that runs a script every time a new `veth` interface is attached?

I have looked into adding scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`, but they do not run when a `veth` is added only during boot.

Here are some syslogs of what I am trying to get notified about. I know I can tail these logs but that method seems sort of hacky and there has to be a way to get notified about this event via the OS.

```
May  2 23:28:41 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170163.565812] netlink: 1 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
May  2 23:28:42 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170163.720571] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth5964: link is not ready
May  2 23:28:42 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170163.720587] device veth5964 entered promiscuous mode
May  2 23:28:42 ip-10-171-7-2 avahi-daemon[1006]: Withdrawing workstation service for vethdc8c.
May  2 23:28:42 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170163.743283] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth5964: link becomes ready
May  2 23:28:42 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170163.743344] docker0: port 27(veth5964) entered forwarding state
May  2 23:28:42 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170163.743358] docker0: port 27(veth5964) entered forwarding state
May  2 23:28:48 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170170.518670] docker0: port 26(vethb06a) entered forwarding state
May  2 23:28:57 ip-10-171-7-2 kernel: [22170178.774676] docker0: port 27(veth5964) entered forwarding state
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a custom `udev` rule that runs a script of yours each time a new interface is added. This is what Debian does for handling interface "hotplug".

`/etc/udev/rules.d/90-my-networking.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net",           RUN+="/usr/local/bin/my-networking-agent.sh"
```

`/usr/local/bin/my-networking-agent.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
logger "hey I just got interface ${INTERFACE} with action ${ACTION}"
```

**EDIT**

Here is how you can test it:

```
# modprobe dummy0
# ifconfig dummy0 up
# tail -n1 /var/log/syslog
May  3 01:48:06 ernst logger: hey I just got interface dummy0 with action add
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was digging through ubuntu network manuals and could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `udev` rules are one of the ways to do it, however there is some shortage of information there, i.e. there is no reliable and simple way to know which container the `veth` is associated with. I am not sure whether in your case it's sufficient to simply set bandwidth limit on the hosts' end of `veth` pair, which might be the cease, but there is also the other end of it in the container's namespace, which is something you can look at using either `ip netns` or `nsenter` commands. So if you do need to operate on both ends of the `veth` pair, it's best to have container ID, so you can lookup the PID and the network namespace associated with it. One way to do it is by running `docker events` and parsing it's output, and yet a better way is to use Docker's domain socket API. For a use case I had earlier, it was sufficient to shell-out to `docker events`  and here is a script I wrote, what it does is add a route inside a container and turn-off the checksum offload with `ethtool`.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

[ ! $# = 2 ] && exit 1;

container_interface="$1"
add_route="$2"

docker events | while read event
do
    echo $event | grep -q -v '\ start$' && continue

    container_id=`echo $event | sed 's/.*Z\ \(.*\):\ .*/\1/'`

    nsenter="nsenter -n -t {{ .State.Pid }} --"
    ip_route_add="ip route add ${add_route} dev ${container_interface} proto kernel scope link src {{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}"
        ethtool_tx_off="ethtool -K ${container_interface} tx off >/dev/null"

    eval `docker inspect --format="${nsenter} ${ip_route_add}; ${nsenter} ${ethtool_tx_off};" ${container_id}`
done
```

In addition to `docker events`, there is another way of catching networking events with `ip monitor` command. However, that  way you still don't have container IDs, similarly to `udev` method.

Comment: Maybe use `docker events --filter 'event=start'` rather than the first grep?